# How to construct regular graphs with girth at least five?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to solve how to construct regular graphs with girth at least five, if girth is five, I know Petersen Graph and a circle satisfy the condition. But is there any other regular graphs with girth five (**In fact I want $k$-regular graphs**)? What if the girth is more than five?

Sincerely thanks your help.

Comment: Well, a cyclic graph on $n$ vertices is 2-regular of girth $n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, I noticed it just now, but I want $k-$regular graphs.

Comment: The graph of a dodecahedron is $3$-regular of girth $5.$

Comment: The point-line incidence graph of a projective plane of order $n$ is an $(n+1)$-regular graph of girth $6.$

Comment: Xavier Dahan, Regular graphs of large girth and arbitrary degree, is available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5259 – see also http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALAPP/Ullery.pdf

Comment: Any thoughts, Lorence, on the comments? Have you had a look at the links?

Comment: Are you still here, Lorence?

Comment: @GerryMyerson So sorry, I did not check the stackexchange  those days. I just downloaded the pdf, thank you very much, I will read it carefully, sorry again.